# MVC C# Redirect to Login Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a login `form` inside a `#myModal` body. The logging in functionality is fine except that if the incorrect username and password are entered, it does not redirect to the `#myModal` with the respective error messages. It instead redirects to the default `login` page. I don't know how to redirect to the `modal` instead of the default `login` page.

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <section id="loginForm">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("E-mail", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBox("email", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Password", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.Password("Password", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Login Controller method**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //how do I redirect back to the login modal if modelstate is invalid?
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
                //how do I redirect back to the login modal?
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can do it with ajax

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't redirect a modal. A modal is part of the page/view. Even though you are clicking on the login button inside the modal, that button performs a POST, which will cause a redirect of the entire page. You will either need to do a POST to your login controller via ajax, or work a redirect into your application flow.